# XML Patterns in Qt 6

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xquery

Qt documentation [reports that some modules are "not supported"](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_6.2.0_Modules)   in Qt 6.2, including the following:

- Qt Win Extras (`qtwinextras`)
- Qt X11 Extras (`qtx11extras`)
- Qt XML Patterns (`qtxmlpatterns`)

What is the actual status of the projects supporting these code bases, in particular XML Patterns, with respect to the possibility of integrating the functionality into applications built on this release and beyond?

Comment: The Qt XML Patterns module provides support for XPath, XQuery, XSLT, and XML Schema validation. If you need any of those, you are better off using a different version then 6.2.

Comment: @wp78de, It would be nice if support were restore in future versions, but one assumes that it is not planned.